# we need to find the aboslute difference between sum of 2 diagonals. Please can u tell me where i am going wrong

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, diagonal

Print the absolute difference between the sums of the matrix's two diagonals as a single integer.

diagonalDifference(arr):
    sum1=0
    sum2=0

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    for j in range(len(arr)):
        if (i==j):
            sum1=sum1+arr[i][j]

        if (((i+j)-1)==(len(arr))):
            sum2=sum2+arr[i][j]
return abs(sum1-sum2)
P.s:
```

Comment: did you try printing out sum1, sum2, i, j and arr[i, j] in every iteration in order to debug?

Comment: There should be a `ParenthesesOverflow` error in Python.

Comment: @SwaggaTing I did try that. BTW I figured out the solution. Thankx for the suggestion

Comment: @Matthias I checked that , no such error exists

Comment: @DivyanshMishra That was a wish. You use way too much parentheses and that makes the code hard to read. `if (((i+j)-1)==(len(arr))):` should be `if i + j - 1 == len(arr):`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is close, you just have the second if statement messed up, it should actually look like this:

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    for j in range(len(arr)):
        if i==j:
            sum1 += arr[i][j]
        if i+j == len(arr)-1:
            sum2 += arr[i][j]
```

example:

```
arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
sum1 #15
sum2 #15
abs(sum1-sum2) #0
```

the length of the array is 3.....
for the second diagonal, the first value is at i=2, j=0 so i+j = 2 which is 3-1
the second value is at i=1, j=1, so i+j = 2 which is 3-1...etc

Comment: hey thankx for telling :) Actually i got bit confused with the representation of matrix like weather the ideal representation for 1*1 matrix is arr[01][02][03] or arr[11][12][13]. Can you update me about it